# What adjective would you choose if you want to elevate a workaholic to a higher degree?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, expressions, adjectives

I want to refer a hard-working person something far more than referring him a mere "workaholic". What adjective should I choose with "workaholic", if I want to refer him as someone working even harder than a workaholic? What adjective would be proper: "ardent workaholic", "unstoppable workaholic", "hyper workaholic", "super workaholic" or any other adjective with "workaholic"? I agree that "workaholic" is a negative term: used for a person who obsessively work for long hours and thereby neglects other aspects of his life. The context in which I want to use the word "workaholic" is a positive one: I want to heap praise on him. What if I refer him a "relentless taskmaster"? Is there any better alternative? Please suggest.

Comment: How about *relentless workaholic*?

Comment: *inveterate* and perhaps *chronic* come to mind.  They don't mix metaphors.  *hopeless* might work along the same lines, as the -aholic suffix implies disease.

Comment: Workaholic has a somewhat negative connotation, like the person works so much that they neglect other elements of their life. Like they're out of balance in an unhealthy way. Do you want to convey that or do you just want to convey that the person works very hard?

Comment: Maybe "a god of obsessive labor."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting "higher degree" to mean that you'd put this particular person ahead (or beyond) a simple workaholic but are trying to describe them **only** in terms of how much of a workaholic they are. If this last point is true then words like "ardent", "unstoppable", and "hyper" each have an issue because they add additional information.  "Super" may work because it doesn't add information beyond a comparison with other (lesser) workaholics.

- Ardent adds an unrequired indication of enthusiasm or passion.
- Unstoppable adds an unrequired indication of inevitability.
- Hyper adds an unrequired indication of energy.

A workaholic may have any, all, or none of those qualities.  Some workaholics are dull.

**Super** workaholic doubles down on the workaholic quality and only the workaholic quality without bringing in other associated, but distict, qualities.  It even manages to work in both negitive and positive contexts since it does not indicate aproval or disaproval.  It's simply an amplifier.

Alternatives to super:
total, serious, extreme

Answer (score 1):

I think the adjective **pathological** could provide the meaning you seek.

> : extreme in a way that is not normal or that shows an illness or
>   mental problem
>
> [Link-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathological)

In US usage, it does not necessarily imply that the person has a actual illness, just that their compulsion is so strong that the effect is similar.  This does imply that this is a harmful state of affairs.

A *pathological workaholic*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the adjective you want is "dedicated" as in "She's dedicated to her job."  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dedicated.  In my opinion this does not have a negative connotation.